# Flexible columns in Tailwind Grid system

Tags: html, css, angular, tailwind-css, css-grid

I am using tailwind grid system , so I have 2 columns , each containing panels. Now one panel of a column extends based on the contents but I do not want the other column panel to extend, so how do I make this happen. Basically height needs to be flexible and would extend based on the content, not affecting other columns/panels. As in example below if 'baz2' extends but shouldn't affect other cells.

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>foo</th>
<th>bar</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>baz</td>
<td>bim</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>baz2...extends</td>
<td>bim3</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Are you saying you want one column to width to be based on the content and the other column width to be fixed?

Comment: Not width, the height. I have a column with a table and rows are added , so the height if container panel extends , which is fine but also the height of other columns increases to be on same level, which I don’t want.